# How to set the Docker Registry with sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to build a Docker image using [sbt-native-packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager) with the following `build.sbt` (trying to publish the image to a local repository)

```scala
val sparkVersion = "2.4.5"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.0"


val sparkLibs = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)

// JAR build settings
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "dzlab",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src",
  scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test",
  resourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test" / "resources",
  javacOptions ++= Seq(),
  scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-deprecation",
    "-feature",
    "-language:implicitConversions",
    "-language:postfixOps"
  ),
  libraryDependencies ++= sparkLibs
)

// Docker Image build settings
dockerBaseImage := "gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v" + sparkVersion

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(
    DockerPlugin,
    JavaAppPackaging
  )
  .settings(
    name := "spark-k8s",
    commonSettings,
    dockerAliases ++= Seq(
      dockerAlias.value.withRegistryHost(Some("localhost:5000"))
    ),
    mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("dzlab.SparkJob")
  )
```

SBT and the packager versions

```sh
$ cat project/plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0")
$ cat project/build.properties 
sbt.version=0.13.18
```

When I try to run the packager

```sh
$ sbt docker:publish
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/dzlab/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/dzlab/Projects/spark-k8s/project
/Users/dzlab/Projects/spark-k8s/build.sbt:39: error: not found: value dockerAliases
    dockerAliases ++= Seq(
    ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

It does not recognize `dockerAliases` not sure why as it is part of the publishing settings.
What is the proper way to set the Docker registry??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sbt-native-packager version is hopelessly outdated, as is your sbt version. That SettingKey doesn't exist in that version.

Compare: [sbt-native-packager 1.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/v1.0.0/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/docker/Keys.scala) vs. [sbt-native-packager 1.7.4](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/v1.7.4/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/docker/Keys.scala)